# in omnicontacts, request.env['omnicontacts.contacts'] is empty in my callback when inviting hotmail contacts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, omnicontacts-gem

I have the gem working for gmail. I can see the list of contacts in

```
@contacts = request.env['omnicontacts.contacts']
```

However, when importing via hotmail, the list is empty. I made sure that I do have hotmail contacts. I double checked every settings in my `live` application (secret key, domain...)

Has anyone had a similar issue ? What can I try to diagnose further ?

**My callback controller:**

```
class Oauth::HotmailController < ApplicationController

  def callback_token
    #this is called.

    #This is empty. When using gmail, contacts are retrieved. But not with hotmail
    @contacts = request.env['omnicontacts.contacts']
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your response from hotmail you have encoded emails.
For example: `"email_hashes":["243c01e30cfdbc8c46b8dddb68a685bb8f86016096fd3398919ed6845fde6b7b"]`

This patch should help:
https://gist.github.com/clouw/5871254